# WPF - How to display the cutom exception from view insted of viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF MMVM application and we are getting xml parser exception from viewmodel method. But the problem is I don't want to show the exception from viewmodel. I would like to show the message from view (`CustomMessageBox.Show()` call from view)

As per the below code, I am calling `CustomMessageBox.Show()` from view model catch block.
How can I call `CustomMessageBox.Show()` from `xaml.cs` or `xaml`?

How can we notify the view about this and call `CustomMessageBox.Showfrom` view?. This code snippet is called in a WPF command.

Current implementation:

```
try
{
  var xamlReader = XamlReader.Parse(xamlText);
  var gb = modelTemplate.GetGraphicalObject("Icons");
  var strings = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Default", xamlText } };
  gb.UpdateGraphicalObject(strings, null, null);
  if (xamlReader != null)
  {
    var view = new Viewbox();
    view.Child = (UIElement)xamlReader;
    view.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    modelVM.Icon = view;
    }
  }
  catch (XamlParseException)
  {
    CustomMessageBox.Show("Invalid XAML file specified.", Properties.Resources.NextGenSim, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    //throw new XamlParseException("Invalid XAML file specified");
  }
```

Comment: @wizzardz Your edit added nothing substantial, the post was fine. All you did was to screw up the indention. Rollback.

Comment: Maybe you can set a property in your ViewModel when the exception is thrown, and bind to that in you View itself.

Comment: Does your MVVM implementation include some sort of `Messenger` class?

Comment: I would like to call CustomMessageBox.Show from the view insted of view model.          Custommessagebox implemented -->CustomMessageBox: Window.  How can i notify viewmodel wxception to view?  We didn't implement any Messenger class

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a messenger / event aggregator (e.g. MVVM Light), you can send a message containing the exceptions details from the viewmodel to the view, which, when received, can trigger the message box to show.

Using [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), it might look like the following:

Viewmodel:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new ErrorMessage("Invalid XAML file specified.",
                       Properties.Resources.NextGenSim));
```

View

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ErrorMessage>(this, message =>
    {
        CustomMessageBox.Show(message.Message, message.Details, 
                              MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
```

The ErrorMessage is a custom class, containing whatever details about the exception you need to display to the user.

Comment: Can i know how can we achive this by event agregator?

Comment: Can i know hoe can we achieve the above with event aggregator ?

Comment: If you're not using a framework like Prism or Caliburn Micro, here's a post called [Roll Your Own Simple Message Bus / Event Aggregator](http://brentedwards.net/2010/04/13/roll-your-own-simple-message-bus-event-aggregator/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a modal `Popup` with Visibility Binding to a ViewModel property `ErrorMessage`, using a `ValueConverter` which returns true when the source given is not null or empty.